# can a motherboard give false hdd errors?

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard, vmware-workstation, hard-drive-recovery

I have a crashed system HP dc7700p  with windows XP pro, due to a failed hdd. The system could not boot up. There was only one harddisk

```
The error displayed was 
 1720 Smart Drive detects imminent failure
  Failing drive Sata0 dark blue
  Failing attribute #184
  To minimize risk of loss blah blah.
```

I took out the disk and but it into my own desktop. When booting up My own pc warned me that there was an immennt failure ...... However i could access all files.

I made an image using acronis backup 11.5. And converted this to a vmware virtual machine. This worked fine and after activating the software i can see that everything is fine in there.

I then restored the image to a physical drive. And tried to boot up on the original pc. But the HDD wasnt availible as a boot up option.

Under boot options there was the 
cd rom drive who had the description Z~Z~Z~Z~Z 
and 
no ide present.

The cd rom doesnt open

Anyway I rebooted a couple of times and got the same error as above except this time it had attribute 7.

I tried then cloning the original hdd using a physical duplicator. But this didnt work as i get a disk read error.

I have now tried the hp recovery disks that i made using the virtual image but that froze during the hardeware configuration check.

Next I tried the HP diagnoses tool (this is with a usb cd rom) this starts up but stops due to an error
CRC error

I am beginning to think that this is a motherboard probæem

Comment: can vmware access your cd burner and write to it? Alternatively, can the HP backup media be made as ISOs  so you can burn it on another machine?

Comment: Just restore the image with Acronis to the new HDD. That seems much easier and quicker then going the roundabout route via the HP backup/restore tools.

Comment: Hi@tonny, i have done that the images wont boot on the restored images

Comment: Without knowing the problems your currently encountering, its not possible for us to determine, if you would have more like with hp restoration software.  Update your question with specifics.

Comment: @ramhound i just updated with more info

Comment: Just to be clear, you have replaced the HDD, since the HDD per the message indicates the HDDs is failing or has failed.

Comment: @ramhound. Yea i have replaced both the old one and the new one.

Comment: The fact the optical disk drive isn't opening indicates a hardware failure.  The most logical conclusion is you have motherboard problems.

Comment: @raymond i am beginning to think that, any way that a weak cmos battery can cause that ?fingers crossed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can a motherboard give false hdd errors?

Sure.  Not only does the motherboard connect to the CPU, and RAM, but modern motherboards often have built-in circuitry for a "hard drive controller" (which used to be part of a separate I/O card on very old (XT) computers).  These things can affect communication with the hard drive.  A perfectly working hard drive can appear bad if it is connected with bad cables, or if it is connected with good cables to a bad motherboard.

> The cd rom doesnt open

Many non-Linux users don't realize this, but software can actually disable the CD-ROM's ability to eject.  That said, if you just turned the system on, CD-ROM's do default to being able to open.  If it isn't opening, that is most likely an issue with power.  Make sure your CD-ROM drive is plugged in.

> I tried then cloning the original hdd using a physical duplicator. But this didnt work as i get a disk read error.

Usually, I just use a computer to duplicate a disk.  But if this "physical duplicator" is a specialized device that copies hard drives, then it sounds like you have multiple devices (the motherboard you've been suspecting, and the duplicator) having issues with the same drive.  That would suggest the problem is with the drive.  Hard drives are among the most common components to fail (and may in fact be the leader in that category...  well, other than non-rechargable batteries in wireless mice and keyboards, which are expected to fail after a certain amount of use, or printers that run out of ink, etc.).

> Under boot options there was the cd rom drive who had the description Z~Z~Z~Z~Z and no ide present.

I've seen such weird stuff before.  This does typically indicate a hardware issue, so your operating system is unlikely to fare any better.  Unfortunately, I've experienced such things with a wide variety of causes, with fixes including:

- a simple power off and back on, permanently fixing
- bad cables
- bad drive
- bad other-components

So, this issue simply tells us there's a problem.  It doesn't help a whole lot in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Super answer Toogam. Today i got my hands on some extra ram and a new psu and changed them. No improvement. I was told that the cd was down for years anyway. I took my original hdd(the first broken one) and installed it in a slightly newer hp machine it booted up with no problwms. So for me it has to be the motherboard.